# Estivemos vs estávamos

Tags: gramática, tempo-verbal, imperfeito-ou-perfeito

> Ontem minha avó e eu **estávamos** na cozinha, falando sobre como é diferente o espanhol que se fala na América do Sul do das Filipinas.
>
> Ontem minha avó e eu **estivemos** na cozinha, falando sobre como é diferente o espanhol que se fala na América do Sul do das Filipinas.

What is the difference between **estivemos** and **estávamos** ? A brazilian told me that **estivemos** is long term and **estávamos** is short term. Are the tenses in Portuguese used in the same way as in Spanish?

Comment: Here is the related, but a lot harder, question [*quando eu era criança vs quando eu fui criança*](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/258/quando-era-uma-crian%C3%A7a-or-quando-fui-uma-crian%C3%A7a/1333#1333)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A short answer:** "estávamos" - first person plural, pretérito imperfeito, indicativo.

> - "nós estávamos na cozinha falando/bebendo/almoçando"
> - "nós estávamos no shopping olhando as vitrines/fazendo compras"

"estivemos" - first person plural, pretérito perfeito, indicativo

> - "nós estivemos no shopping olhando as vitrines
> - "nós estivemos na cozinha e na área de serviço, mas não vimos a sala e os quartos."

In context, "nós estávamos na cozinha" means that we were there for some time and probably doing something (eating, talking, etc) whereas "nós estivemos" means only that we entered and then left, probably for a short period of time but not necessarily so.

In English "nós estávamos na cozinha falando..." would be something like

> "we were talking in the kitchen..."

and "nós estivemos na cozinha"

> "we went into the kitchen for a few minutes" or "we've been to the kitchen".

****The same applies to **"Eu estava na França"** and **"Eu estive na França"**.  The former translates as **"I was in France"** and the latter as **"I've been to France".**

Comment: Your translation seems very adequate. `Eu estava na França` as `I was in France` and `Eu estive na França`as `I've been to/in France`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I find this answer quite poor. 1) the 1st two sentences make no sense without adding something else "estávamos sempre na cozinha", "estávamos na cozinha quando..."; 2) you basically don't explain any difference: «"nós estávamos na cozinha" means that we were there for some time», «"nós estivemos" means only that we entered and then left» (similar to me). 3) Your examples in English are somewhat helpful, but  may give the idea of a correspondence of tenses between the two languages that doesn't exist AND your sentences are not analogous ("were talking" vs "went into the kitchen").

Answer (score 7):

The ***pretérito imperfeito (PI)***, *estávamos*, means the event started before the reference time and continued after the reference time. The ***pretérito perfeito (PP)***, *estivemos*, means the event coincides with or is contained within the reference time. I think this is also the case in Spanish, but you tell me.

In your examples the reference time is “ontem” or *yesterday*. To facilitate the explanation, let’s suppose yesterday was Tuesday. The first sentence, with *estávamos*, sounds a bit strange, because strictly it means the two of you were continuously in the kitchen for more than 24 hours, from some time before Tuesday until some time after Tuesday, for instance from 11 pm on Monday until 2 am on Wednesday. The second sentence, with *estivemos*, means that the whole of your talk in the kitchen took place Tuesday.

Let’s illustrate the use of *estávamos* with some more plausible examples:

> (a) Onde é que eu e a minha avó ***estávamos*** ao meio dia? ***Estávamos*** na cozinha.

Here the reference time is *meio dia*, so *estávamos* implies you and your granny had been in the kitchen from some time before 12 noon and stayed there for some time after 12 noon. If you said instead “estivemos na cozinha ao meio dia” you would mean that you went there and came out again immediately, perhaps to pick up something. Another example:

> (b) Ontem a minha avó e eu ***estávamos*** falando na cozinha, e de repente chegou o João.

Here the reference time is the moment when João arrives, and the *estávamos* implies that you were in the kitchen before that moment already, and were still there after that moment. With *estivemos* the sentence would sound strange, and if heard it I would ask for a clarification.

It should be clear by now that short-term and long-term business is neither here nor there. If the time frame is the same, *estávamos* implies a longer duration than *estivemos*, but both can be used for both long and short time spans. For instance:

> (c) O Manuel ***esteve*** vinte anos na prisão.
>
> (d) O João ***esteve*** aqui, mas não mais de dois minutos.
>
> (e) A guerra colonial portuguesa foi de 1961 a 1974. Nesse altura o Manuel ***estava*** na prisão.
>
> (f) Ouvi a campainha tocar mas não pôde ir à porta porque ***estava*** no banheiro. (Só estive lá um minuto, mas foi o suficiente para não conseguir chegar à porta antes de te ires embora.)

The event coincides with the reference time in (c) (twenty years) and is contained in the time reverence in (d) (two minutes), so you use the *pretérito perfeito*. In (e) and (f) the *pretérito imperfeito* implies the opposite, that the event started before the reference time (1961-74 in (e) and when the bell rang in (f)) and continued after it.

A couple of examples more. Let me know if you need explanation:

> (g) Na quinta feira passada ***estávamos*** em Madrid. ***Estivemos*** lá a semana inteira, de domingo a sábado.
>
> (h) No Natal passado ***estávamos*** em Angola. ***Estivemos*** lá dois anos a trabalhar.
>
> (i) Disseram-me que ***estiveste*** em minha casa às sete da tarde. A essa hora eu ainda ***estava*** no trabalho.

Comment: Boa resposta. A minha dúvida, quando olhei para isto e sendo uma frase claramente brasileira, era se não era uma construção progressiva encapuçada ("estávamos falando na sala"), mas mesmo que fosse não creio que alterasse significativamente a análise.

Comment: @Artefacto Também pensei nisso (que é aliás a construção no meu segundo exemplo) e também acho que não mudava nada. Teríamos só que tirar a vírgula.

Answer (score 3):

> A brazilian told me that estivemos is long term and estavamos is short term.

I would rather say the opposite: with `estivemos` the event is taken as punctual while with `estávamos` the event is taken as durative. I say "taken as" because it is just how the fact is used in the sentence, not necessarily reflecting its actual duration.

In practice, the imperfect tense `estávamos` is used when there is a reference (possibly implicit) to something else that happened during that time. For instance,

> Ontem minha avó e eu estávamos na cozinha, falando sobre como é diferente o espanhol que se fala na América do Sul do das Filipinas, quando o meu pai entrou na sala e mudou de assunto.

Or when the duration of the event is important:

> -- Onde vocês estavam (esse tempo todo)? 
>   -- Estávamos na cozinha.

Myself, I would only use `estivemos` if nothing relevant happened during the time we were in the kitchen, and probably only listing a lot of places where we were (that's what I mean by punctual events, they're like a lot of points being listed):

> Estivemos na cozinha, na sala, no banheiro, mas não vimos João em lugar algum.

Comment: Interessante: eu diria «onde vocês estavam?» ou «onde vocês estiveram?», mas apenas «onde vocês estiveram esse tempo todo?»

Comment: As duas formas parecem-me naturais e equivalentes em muitos contextos. Ainda assim, eu diria `onde vocês estavam esse tempo todo?` se eu esperasse como resposta uma atividade única como `assistindo TV` ou `andando pelo shopping`, ao passo que diria `onde vocês estiveram esse tempo todo?` se eu esperasse uma lista como `estivemos no shopping, na praia, depois ficamos aqui mesmo`.